# Ipython crashing on startup

Tags: ipython

What the title says.  I'm very confused.  Here's a transcript:

```
> ipython
if: Empty if.
>
```

Has anyone seen this error before?
This started after I installed a package with pip.  The package installed successfully.

I am on Mac OS 10.10, with ipython 3.2, python 2.7

Comment: can you add your operating system, python and ipython version ?

Comment: sorry! I edited the question to include that.

Comment: Does the `ipython` script (you can find it with `which ipython`) start with a line like `#!/usr/bin/env python`?

Comment: yes:

`#!/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/bin/python`

Comment: Googling that error message, it's a shell (probably csh) error, which means that for some reason your computer is trying to run IPython as a shell script, instead of as a Python program.